# How do I multiply with 0.8 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**2020 edit: I was young and dumb and did not know how multiplication worked.**

So, I need to embed a youtube video on a site, and I want it to take up 80% of the user's screen size. I found the following code to make it fullscreen. Can someone help me make it fullscreen -20%?

```
    $(function(){
  $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to multiply by `0.8`?

Comment: @Amy Yes I was. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the `width` and `height` of the `window` by `0.8` to get 80% of the width and height of the fullscreen.

```
$(function(){
  $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth()*0.8 + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight()*0.8 + 'px' });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth()*0.8 + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight()*0.8 + 'px' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly, I tried to divide it and that did not work.

Comment: @FCD No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think where you have width: `$(window).innerWidth() + 'px'`... you are saying let the width be the entirety of the page, the same with height.

Can you divide the `$(window).innerWidth()` by a certain size, such as 300?
That may change the size of the video for you.

Such as:

```
var smallerWidthWindow = window.innerHeight / 250; //(or required number)
```

then have width: smallerWidthWindow and height: smallerHeightWindow, using those variables to change your height and width.

```
$('#video').css({ width: smallerWidthWindow, height: smallerHeightWindow });
```